# Передача многомерного ассоциативного массива Javascript - PHP через XMLHttpRequest. $_POST записывает массив в ключ. Как правильно сериализовать JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

Задача - передавать n-мерные ассоц. массивы, на чистом javascript AJAX (XMLHttpRequest).

```
function send(encoded) {
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", 'https://');
r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
r.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
r.send(encoded);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (r.readyState === 4){
console.log(r.response);
}}

// Данные для передачи 1
var block = {"datablock": {"321": 264785}};
var encoded = JSON.stringify(block); // выдаёт {"datablock":{"321":264785}}
send(encoded);
```

Проблема в том, что $_POST, получив данные, сразу записывает весь массив в ключ, который равен пустой строке.

Ответ сервера 1:

```
echo(var_dump($_POST));

Arrayarray(1) {
  ["{"datablock":{"321":264785}}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Пробовал делать всё строкой вручную:

```
// Данные для передачи 2
var block = {"datablock": {"321": 264785}};
var test = JSON.stringify(block);
var encoded = "text:" + test; // выдаёт text:{"datablock":{"321":264785}}
send(encoded);
```

Ответ сервера 2:

```
echo(var_dump($_POST));
Arrayarray(1) {
  ["text:{"datablock":{"321":264785}}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Насколько понял, с тем как $_POST обрабатывает данные сделать ничего нельзя?

Остаётся вопрос - как сформировать передаваюмую JSON строку, чтобы $_POST обработал её правильно. Из других веток понял, что передаваемые данные сами должны быть "под ключом", чтобы $_POST мог его использовать. Но, как не пытаюсь, все данные всё равно записываются в ключ, равный пустой строке.

Здесь есть решение через jQuery AJAX. Но, не ясно как сериализовать без jQuery.
[JSON, AJAX и многомерный ассоциативный “массив” - jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/680919)

Здесь расписана сериализация, может у меня где-то ошибка, но результат тот же.
[Простые вещи: Сериализация массива в JavaScript для последующей десериализации в PHP.](https://habr.com/ru/post/41997/)

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: В массив $_POST JSON данные нормально не примутся. Выполните json_decode() полученных данных

Comment: 1) Для json_decode() требуется указать ключ, например json_decode($_POST['ключ']), а у меня весь массив в ключе.
2) Я уже как-то умудрялся сделать json_decode() - результат NULL, т.к. данные в ключе, а в значении только пустая строка, string(0).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/ Только думаю при передаче из js надо указывать Content-type application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Mike за ответ [как получить данные до обработки в $_POST](http://geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php)

1) Данные для передачи - массив ассоциативных массивов глубины 2, через JSON.stringify.
При отправке установил r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"), хотя разницы с application/x-www-form-urlencoded не увидел, наверное срабатывает автоопределение при неправильном типе. Обработка в PHP:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($input, true);
```

2) Чтобы всё-таки использовать $_POST, можно пробовать форматирование в строку вида:
"name=value,value,value..." - тогда $_POST их может нормально обработать, записав name в ключ. Только, name=, при этом, кодировать в json не надо. Т.е. вручную сделать то, что делает serialize в jQuery с формами.  Примерно так, точно не помню, т.к. это получилось ночью и я в итоге применил первый вариант.